# XML Namespace error in WSDL file

Tags: xml, namespaces, wsdl, xml-namespaces, xml-validation

I have the following service definition (incomplete, but demonstrates the error.
Visual Studio tells me (translated from german) "In this Schema Namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/ is not available" at the line where I define OffertXML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="TestOffertverwaltung"
 targetNamespace="urn:TestOffertverwaltung"
 xmlns:tns="urn:TestOffertverwaltung"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:types="urn:Test/types"
 xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
 xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
 xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime"
 xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

    <wsdl:types>

        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:Test/types">

            <xsd:element name="OffertXML" type="string"/>
            <xsd:element name="OffertPDF" xmime:expectedContentTypes='image/jpeg' type="xmime:base64Binary"/>
            <xsd:element name="OffertMeta" type="string"/>
            <xsd:element name="OffertId" type="string"/>

        </xsd:schema>

    </wsdl:types>

<!-- ... -->
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your type with

```
type="xsd:string"
```

Currently use are setting the type to string in the default namespace which is http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/string, hence which is a type which is not available.

Comment: Why is it not available? The surrounding element is in namespace xsd.

Comment: Just because the surrounding element is in the xsd namespace that does not change the default namespace (xmlns="...") - this is what the types will be expanded against.